# Compare column values in consecutive rows in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, dataset, pyspark

I am new to Spark Scala. I am having a situation where I have to compare values of a particular column in a data set, for example:

### Source Data

```
Source  Destination Distance
Austin  Houston     200
Dallas  Houston     400
Kansas  Dallas      700
```

### Resultant

```
Source1  Destination1   Distance1   Source2  Destination2 Distance2  DistDiff     
Dallas   Houston        400         Kansas   Dallas       700        300
```

As per the situation, I have to compare the distance of subsequent rows and if the difference is more than or equals to 300 then save the records in the Resultant data set
700 - 400 = 300

The examples which I have encountered are having functions which are executing on per row basis on any particular data set, however my scenario is to play with consecutive rows.

Comment: Spark RDD/DataFrame entries are not ordered. So how do plan on maintaining order ?

Comment: I did something like this recently... you can hack together something that works for the majority of the time using `mapPartitions`. No matter what, you end up dropping data at the edges of portions though.

Comment: It will be ordered by datetime which I have not included into the example.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you can sort rows by datetime. So, assuming it's sorted using `sortBy` or `sortByKey` to create an *ordered* rdd, and also assuming you have an even number of rows (so each row has another one to calculate difference with) you can:

1. Give each row an index using `zipWithIndex`.
2. Split the RDD into two RDDs, one with even-numbered indices and one with odd-numbered indices, by filtering on the index created.
3. `zip` the split RDDs together, creating a new RDD of `Tuple2` with even-indexed rows on the left and odd-indexed rows on the right.
4. `map` the result to calculate the difference between left/right of each row.

Comment: contact me if you are open to remote work for a few days.  We need scala/sparkexpertise that you have

Comment: This is not a complete answer. Firstly, this will only calculate the differences between the even rows and the odd ones preceding them. It will *not* calculate the differences between the odd rows and the even ones preceding *them*. Secondly, no mention is made about the rdd partitions. This is important, because the zipping won't work if the rdd's are not partitioned in the same way (in pyspark at least).

Answer (score 1):

This may be done in the following way:

1. Add an index column to your sorted rdd
2. Make sure the rdd has an even number of rows N
3. Make an rdd *rdd_even1* to contain the even rows with indices [0, N-2]
4. Make an rdd *rdd_odd1* to contain the odd rows [1, N-1]
5. Make an rdd *rdd_even2* to contain the even rows [2, N-2]
6. Make an rdd *rdd_odd2* to contain the odd rows [1, N-3]
7. Now you need to repartition *rdd_even1* and *rdd_odd1 before zipping, because zipping won't work if both rdd's do not have the same number of elements in all partitions (in pyspark at least). You can do it in memory using *collect* and *parallelize*, but most likely you have to write the rdd's to HDFS and re-read them, controlling for the paritioning
8. Do the same for *rdd_even2* and *rdd_odd2*
9. zip the rdd's from step 7 to *rdd_zip1*
10. zip the rdd's from step 8 to *rdd_zip2*
11. Call *rdd_zip1.union(rdd_zip2)*
12. Now you can call *map()* on the union to get your "resultant" with the required differences

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! Also note that it's possible to directly modify the partitioning of an RDD using [repartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#repartition). In this case, since both even/odd RDDs will have the same size (you can pad one of them to ensure this), that should give you a matching partitioning for `zip`.